# how to save the published data of a topic for using in matlab

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I am using rviz for monitoring the path planning of my mobile robot. It is easily possible to subscribe to a topic and visualize the results data. I wonder how I can save the data of planned path by the planner. I can save topics in a bag file but the problem is that I cannot extract and use them in other software. More clearly, I need to plot this path in Matlab software. Does anybody have any idea how to do it? How do I extract this information from a bag file or Is there any other way to save this data in another format which is usable in Matlab?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249491/how-to-save-the-published-data-of-a-topic-for-using-in-matlab/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest method is probably to convert the data in the bag file to a csv file, have a look at this topic for some suggestions how to do that:

[how to extract data from a bag](http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/)

Matlab is capable of loading the csv files and for a description of how one person did that you can even have a look over here:
[exporting ros bag files to matlab](http://nimbus.unl.edu/2014/11/exporting-ros-bag-files-to-matlab/)

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-07**:
No need to convert to `csv` if you have the *Robotic System Toolbox*. See [Open and parse rosbag log file](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rosbag.html).